# Decay for the tail of a series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $p>1$.  I would like to have an estimate for the  decay of the sequence  $s_{n}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}k^{-p}$. Does anyone know of a bound of this type in the literature?
Thanks!

Comment: You can easily derive one from the integral test.

Comment: Do you mean $k^{-p}$?  As written the sum diverges.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Surely he does. It is interesting to note how easy it is to overlook such trivial mistakes.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen:  We have had interest recently in expressions like $\sum i = -\frac 1{12}$, so I was checking.  I was writing up the same answer as Tom Cooney when I noticed it.  I make these mistakes, too.

Comment: The case where $p=2$ was examined in detail at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685435/trying-to-get-a-bound-on-the-tail-of-the-series-for-zeta2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the proof of the integral test of convergence for a sequence; we identify $s_n$ as upper and lower Riemann sums of integrals to get the bounds:
$$
\int_{n+1}^\infty x^{-p} \ dx \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p} \leq \int_{n}^\infty x^{-p} \ dx.
$$
Evaluating the integrals, we then have
$$
\frac{1}{p-1} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{p}} \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^p} \leq \frac{1}{p-1} \frac{1}{n^p}.
$$

Comment: For finer-grained estimates based on refinements of the above idea, please see the [Euler-Maclaurin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) summation formula.